# How to use legacy providers and directives in new bootstrapModule introduced in angular rc.5

Tags: angular

Earlier I had a bootstrap call in `main.ts` like:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    disableDeprecatedForms(),
    provideForms(),
    {
        provide: PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, multi: true, useValue: MATERIAL_DIRECTIVES
    }
])
```

In short, Angular rc.4 -> rc.5 [migration guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/rc4-to-rc5.html) suggests a new way to bootstrap an app i.e. `bootstrapModule` which initializes the root module:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(
    AppModule
)
```

**Question:**
How do we pass the legacy / custom directives and providers when using `bootstrapModule` instead of the older `bootstrap` call?

**My guess is:**
These providers and directives should be included somewhere within  `app.module.ts`, but how exactly would we wrap these directives and providers using the module, is not clear to me?

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],

    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule,
    ],

    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html

<strike>Seems this guide is not yet online at http://angular.io https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/master/public/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.jade and the examples in https://github.com/angular/angular.io/tree/master/public/docs/_examples/ngmodule/ts</strike>

Create an `AppModule` https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/master/public/docs/_examples/ngmodule/ts/app/app.module.1.ts

> ```ts
> @NgModule({
>   imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
>   declarations: [
>     AppComponent,
>     HighlightDirective,
>     TitleComponent,
>
>     AwesomePipe,
>     ContactComponent,
>     ContactHighlightDirective
>   ],
>   providers: [ UserService ],
>   bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
> })
> export class AppModule { }
> ```

> ```ts
> platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
> ```

Comment: Perfect! Also, just found the ngModule docs online; https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html

Comment: Thanks. I checked twice and didn't see them :D

Comment: "@angular/forms": "0.2.0", does not support in @NgModule() ? How can I use appRouterProviders,  disableDeprecatedForms() ?  It gives me this error message "node_modules/@angular/forms/index"' has no exported member 'FormsModule'."

Comment: providers not working. can't call from the constructor of component

Comment: @anusree sorry, no idea what your comment means.